# NPM - How to install transitive dependencies pointing to git URL?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm using transitive dependencies that point to git URLs (not on GitHub) and I've found that NPM skips over these dependencies when installing the direct parent dependency.

For example, let's say I have package `A`, which has a dependency `B`:

```
"B": "git+https://username:password@giturl.com/username/B"
```

Now in a new project, `C`, I install `A`.

```
npm i git+https://username:password@giturl.com/username/A
```

Now if I look at `C`'s package.json and package-lock.json, I can't find `B` anywhere! Interestingly enough, if I then install `B` manually:

```
npm i git+https://username:password@giturl.com/username/B
```

then `B` shows up in `C`'s package.json and package-lock.json, both as a transitive dependency for `A` and a direct dependency for `C`.

It's also worth mentioning that this behavior does not occur when using github.com, only when using custom git hosts.

Is there any way around this so I don't have to manually install all my transitive dependencies each time? I'd like NPM to behave like it does for github.com.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, although I'm bewildered as to *why* NPM decided to **skip over** these dependencies. I'm assuming it's a bug and have filed a [report](https://npm.community/t/npm-will-skip-over-transitive-dependencies-that-point-to-non-github-urls/9936).

I added the [`--global-style`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) flag to my `npm install` command, and NPM will now install my transitive dependencies, except now I don't get the benefits of deduping. `--legacy-bundling` (disables deduping) also seems to do the trick - which leads me to believe the problem lies in deduping.

> The --global-style argument will cause npm to install the package into
>   your local node_modules folder with the same layout it uses with the
>   global node_modules folder. Only your direct dependencies will show in
>   node_modules and everything they depend on will be flattened in their
>   node_modules folders. This obviously will eliminate some deduping.